# sidebar with color down page, html, css

Tags: html, css, sidebar

I have this code in a blade file currently, and its so CLOSE to what I need. However, I can't quite get the sidebar element to have color all the way down, as in a column.

*edited, html was removed in earlier version

```
<style>

    ul.products li {
        width: 200px;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
    }

    body{
        background: white;
    }

    #wrapper { overflow:auto; }

    #content {
        float: right; width: 80%;
        margin:5px 0 5px 0;
    }

    #sidebar {
        float: left;
        width: 20%;
        background: #F9F8F2 repeat-y;
    }

</style>

<body>
<div id="wrapper">

    <div id="sidebar">
        <ul>
            <li>Sidebar stuff.</li>
            <li>Sidebar stuff.</li>
            <li>Sidebar stuff.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div id="content">
        <ul class="products">
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="logo.png">
                    <h4>text</h4>
                    <p>$20.00</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">
                    <img src="logo.png">
                    <h4>text</h4>
                    <p>$25.00</p>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: add your html codes please

Comment: oh hell i thought i had it all code-wrapped. fixed.

Comment: all the way down to viewport's bottom or all the way down to last sidebar content?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
#sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    background-color: #F9F8F2;
}
```

"background" set different background properties in one declaration. Often if you miss a property or make a typo it will not display correctly. You can check the documentation here:

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.asp

Answer (score 0):

> I can't quite get the sidebar element to have color all the way down, as in a column.

**1.** Flexbox solution (recommended):

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background: white;
}
#wrapper {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}
#sidebar {
  /* float: left; */
  flex: 1;
  width: 20%;
  background: #F9F8F2;
}
ul li {
  /*width: 200px;*/
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
ul {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="sidebar">
    <ul>
      <li>Sidebar stuff.</li>
      <li>Sidebar stuff.</li>
      <li>Sidebar stuff.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**2.** Without altering `#sidebar` position property solution:

```css
html,
body {
  background: white;
  height: 100%;
}
#wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
#sidebar {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  background: #F9F8F2 repeat-y;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="sidebar">
    <ul class="products">
      <li>Sidebar stuff.</li>
      <li>Sidebar stuff.</li>
      <li>Sidebar stuff.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**3.** With `absolute` `position` `#sidebar` solution:

```css
body {
  background: white;
}
#wrapper {
  overflow: auto;
}
#sidebar {
  /* float: left; */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 20%;
  background: #F9F8F2;
}
ul li {
  /* width: 200px;*/
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
ul {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="sidebar">
    <ul>
      <li>Sidebar stuff.</li>
      <li>Sidebar stuff.</li>
      <li>Sidebar stuff.</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: flex` to `#wrapper`:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vgLWQL

The height of the container/page can be dynamic here, it adjusts to whichever of the two elements has more content, but both will have the same height.

ADDITION:

I added `min-height: 100vh;` to the `#wrapper` to make it at least as high as the window.